# How Optimize sql query make it faster

Tags: sqlite, optimization, performance, inner-join

I have a very simple small database, 2 of tables are:

**Node** (`Node_ID, Node_name, Node_Date`) : Node_ID is primary key
**Citation** (`Origin_Id, Target_Id`) : `PRIMARY KEY (Origin_Id, Target_Id)` each is FK in Node

Now I write a query that first find all citations that their Origin_Id has a specific date and then I want to know what are the target dates of these records.

I'm using sqlite in python the Node table has 3000 record and Citation has 9000 records,
and my query is like this in a function:

```
def cited_years_list(self, date):
    c=self.cur
    try:
    c.execute("""select n.Node_Date,count(*) from Node n INNER JOIN 
              (select c.Origin_Id AS Origin_Id, c.Target_Id AS Target_Id, n.Node_Date AS 
               Date from CITATION c INNER JOIN NODE n ON c.Origin_Id=n.Node_Id where
               CAST(n.Node_Date as INT)={0}) VW ON VW.Target_Id=n.Node_Id 
               GROUP BY n.Node_Date;""".format(date))
    cited_years=c.fetchall()
    self.conn.commit()
    print('Cited Years are : \n ',str(cited_years))
    except Exception as e:
       print('Cited Years retrival failed ',e)
   return cited_years
```

Then I call this function for some specific years, But it's crazy slowwwwwwwww :(  (around 1 min for a specific year)
Although my query works fine, it is slow. would you please give me a suggestion to make it faster? I'd appreciate any idea about optimizing this query :)

I also should mention that I have indices on Origin_Id and Target_Id, so the inner join should be pretty fast, but it's not!!!

Comment: Why are you performing the count(*)?

Comment: Also include your full schema for the tables

Comment: Hi, this data is about court cases, and I want to know that "for a specific year, how far in time they cite previous cases, and if for example they cite 2 cases in 1990 I want to know that they are 2". In another word, I use count(*) because I want to understand the distribution of target_ID date for a specific Origion_ID. is it clear?

Answer (score 1):

If this script runs over a period of time, you may consider loading the database into memory. Since you seem to be coding in python, there is a connection function called connection.backup that can backup an entire database into memory. Since memory is much faster than disk, this should increase speed. Of course, this doesn''t do anything to optimize the statement itself, since I don't have enough of the code to evaluate what it is you are doing with the code.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer, I may do it, but the thing that is strange for me is that this query take about 1 min for a specific date, which is insane. it's only a join and a condition , that should be pretty fast! I also have indices on the target_ID , Origin_ID, I really don't know what's wrong, is it related to sqlite ? I paste my whole function inside my question, do u have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of COUNT(*)  use MAX(n.Node_Date)

SQLite doesn't keep a counter on number of tables like mysql does but instead it scans all your rows everytime you call COUNT meaning extremely slow.. yet you can use MAX() to fix that problem.